# Joomla 4: Is there any method to deregister JavaScript for specific page

Tags: javascript, joomla, disable, joomla4

I am trying to deregister few code Java script on specific page, I have been using below code but JavaScript does not removing from page.

```
$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->disableScript('core');
```

But is is not working, any idea of suggestion about how to disable or remove js from specific page in Joomla 4?